# 60s or earlier sci-fi novel: alien visits a now lifeless Earth for research, synthesizes food, and wants to have emotions like humans had

Tags: story-identification, novel

Things I remember:

- An alien is visiting Earth.
- There is no longer life on the planet.
- The alien is doing research.
- I don't remember a whole lot more except that

  - The alien somehow synthesizes food (specifically butter).
  - He then begins to like what he's done and ...

That's all I really remember for sure. I vaguely remember the alien rebelled against authority and wanted to "enjoy" having emotions like humans had. As I recall, the alien liked the fact of experiencing emotions. Something his society had long since lost the use of. The alien may have have no body at all, although I do not remember for sure.

I'm in the US although the book may have been UK. The book I read was a paperback and probably less than 200 pages. I do not remember what the cover looked like.

Comment: And.... and what?

Comment: I have edited the points you mention into your question. You might want to have a quick read through and make sure I've fairly represented your comments.

Comment: @Valorum dies of cholesterol overdose